# How to stop details section backgrounds spreading horizontally in the exported Excel file of a Crystal Report

Tags: excel, crystal-reports, export

In my exported Excel file background color of two sections spread all over horizontally as shown in the following image:

[image]

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the margins of the crystal reports.. your margins of your data is extending to second page... so details colour is extending horizontally.. check the fields and limit to the design of the report.

Comment: I have multiple subreport details sections in whole report and everything seems to be fine. In these problematic sections I have only couple of text objects and nothing is going out of the sections (from designer point of view).

Comment: In preview.. is the report extending horizontally?

Comment: No, in the preview mode everything is ok (And yes, the preview mode is like PDF export). And I have margins of 1cm on the left and on the right. Here is the shoot of the preview: http://s11.postimg.org/sldlmoxxf/Excel_Problem01.png

Comment: Yes... I have Office 2010 Professional Plus and I was in the "Exporting Settings" and did not find anything useful for this issue. By the way, my main report is complex, it has 10 subreports and this is the vertical column Excel preview which does not look ok I guess: http://s18.postimg.org/48d6frznt/Excel_Problem02.png